# form not sending data?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I cant for the life of me figure this out.

I have the following form which, when submitted, returns an empty array?
Its going to the right page when submitted (index.php) but its not passing anything as either GET or POST. Both return nothing using var_dump($_POST). Any ideas?

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="orderName">What is your name?</label>
        <input type="textbox" class="form-control" id="orderName" aria-describedby="orderName" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="orderEmail">What is your email address?</label>
        <input type="textbox" class="form-control" id="orderEmail" aria-describedby="orderEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="orderCopies">How many copies of the book would you like?</label>
        <input type="textbox" class="form-control" id="orderCopies" aria-describedby="orderCopies" placeholder="Enter amount of books">
        <small id="oderCopiesHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Note: each book is $35 (including postage)</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="orderAddress">Where would you like the book/s sent to?</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="orderAddress" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="orderComments">Order comments</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="orderComments" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>             
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send order</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Your input tags should also contain name attributes for the PHP array to contain key values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input needs `name` attribute which is missing in your markup.

**For example,**

```
<input type="textbox" class="form-control" name="orderName" id="orderName" aria-describedby="orderName" placeholder="Enter name">
```

**Your code with `name`  attributes on `<input>`, `<textarea>` and `<button>`:**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="orderName">What is your name?</label>
        <input type="textbox" class="form-control" name="orderName" id="orderName" aria-describedby="orderName" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="orderEmail">What is your email address?</label>
        <input type="textbox" class="form-control" name="orderEmail" id="orderEmail" aria-describedby="orderEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="orderCopies">How many copies of the book would you like?</label>
        <input type="textbox" class="form-control" name="orderCopies" id="orderCopies" aria-describedby="orderCopies" placeholder="Enter amount of books">
        <small id="oderCopiesHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Note: each book is $35 (including postage)</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="orderAddress">Where would you like the book/s sent to?</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="orderAddress" id="orderAddress" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="orderComments">Order comments</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="orderComments" id="orderComments" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>             
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submitButton">Send order</button>
</form>
```

Comment: True. In the PHP file then you should do `$VarName = $_POST['Here goes the name of your input'];`

Comment: You could then print the input by doing `echo $VarName`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add name attribute tags for each input element. The name attribute and value gets sent via the post method to the script to receive it.

Answer (score 0):

For each input tag always put the name attribute to pass the form data.

Ex.

```
<input type="textbox" class="form-control" id="orderName" name="orderName" aria-describedby="orderName" placeholder="Enter name">
```